# Getting list of FB friends of user

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am planning to develop an  android app where in i need to get a list of my friends.Now the new open graph v2 fb API doesnot allow the app to get list of all its friends.

[Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m)

I can use `user_taggable_friends` permission to get list of friends.But then i need to get the app reviewed.For review process my app needs to provide them apk .But  unless i have users friends list(all friends , not only one using my app) my app is useless.

How do i go about this?

Also i dont want to wait for review.Can i get around by using user/invitable_friends API?

Whats the difference between user/invitable_friends and me/taggable_friends?

Comment: hey u got any solution for this issue..?coz i get same issue with fb api 2.0 for getting Facebook user friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to develop and test the app with your administrative users. For those you'll not need to have your app reviewed to be able to request extended permissions.